# SharePoint 2010 FBA InfoPath access denied to webservice

Tags: 2010, infopath, claims-based-auth

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application using Claims based authentication.

- Anonymous access enabled
- Windows authentication enabled, integrated Windows authentication, NTLM
- Forms Based Authentication (FBA) enabled

Im using InfoPath form on a list. Using InfoPath I have created a dataconnection to the webservice https:///_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDL with the operation GetUserProfileByName

When opening item in list:

- An error occured querying a data source. Log ID: 5566

ULS Log viewer:

- Access denied calling web service for user.
- Data adapter failed during OnLoad: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
- The following query failed: GetUserProfileByName (User: 0#.f|aspnetmembership|user)

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: Did you check accessing the webservice via browser? Did you check accessing the webservice in InfoPath before publishing it into the list?

Comment: Access via browser is ok. Preview in InfoPath fails. I also tested the webservice on a webapplication which is using only Windows auth and that works fine with InfoPath. I ended up using userName() in InfoPath, which returns blank value for FBA users and current username for Windows users - which gives me a ok solution for creating a rule to switch view based on FBA/Windows users.

Comment: See this post -

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/why-is-getuserprofilebyname-from-infopath-forms-services-with-claims-authenticat/33083#33083